# Swift: Runtime: Threading Issues: Data race in MyApp.DownloadManager.progress.setter : Swift.Float at 0x7b1400209130

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, xcode9

While running ThreadSanitizer in my app I got a Data race issue while concurrent downloading file, how to solve it

Here is the breakpoint code:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten:
    Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    if let downloadUrl = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString,

        let download = activeDownloads[downloadUrl] {
       //break point indicate here:-
        download.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

        let totalSize = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalBytesExpectedToWrite, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let trackIndex = self.trackIndexForDownloadTask(downloadTask), let trackCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: trackIndex, section: 0)) as? AmbientCell {

                trackCell.progressView.progress = Double(download.progress)
                if download.progress == 1.0 {
                 trackCell.progressView.isHidden = true
                 trackCell.downloadCompleted.isHidden = false
                }
             }
        })
    }
}
```

full warning log - [ThreadSanitizer: data race](https://gist.github.com/abdulKarim002/6584c7efbd0579072631d9c18d712492)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a single download manager that's used concurrently from two threads, and you're setting its progress in both threads, which is causing the error.
First of all, why? If you're downloading two different files, they shouldn't be sharing the progress. If it's the same file, should it be really downloaded concurrently?
In the latter case you may want to protect the shared download manager with a mutex. Note that even in this case you may still update the progress with non-monotonic values.